# Add an extra column to the word file

Tags: python

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
1 0.0
2 0.2
3 0.4
```

What  I want to do now is to check whether certain values are between thresholds and then add something to the line. So if the values is 0.1 and thereby between 0 and 0.2 "1" should be added and the output should be:

```
1 0.0 1
2 0.2
3 0.4
```

I tried this:

```
#open doc
doc = "sample_name.txt"
f = open(doc, "r")
lines = l.readlines()

count = 1 
for line in lines:

 elements = line.split(" ")
 start_time = elements[1]

 #get element from next line
 next_line = lines[count]
 elements_new_line = next_line.split(" ")
 end_time = element_new_line[1]

 if i >= end_time and i <= start_next_time:
     #add a one the file
 #increase counter
 count = count + 1
```

Any thoughts on how I write the 1 to .txt file

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more..give some examples

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking, it's generally not altogether easy to add values to the ends of lines in a text file. This is because adding even one character to a line involves 'pushing' all the other characters in the file to the right. Usually, the preferred gambit is to read lines of the input file, add or modify characters as necessary to these lines and write them to an output file. In your case, the input file can then be discarded and the output file put in its place.

I have written the following code to use `with` when opening the input and output files, so that they are automatically closed upon exit from the indentation of the `with`. This is now the preferred way of working with files.

My assumption is that there only two values per line called `first` and `second`. I used `strip` to remove any line-feed or carriage-return characters at the end of each line. I use an `if` to test the input value. You  will note that it's necessary to convert from characters read to floating-point to make the comparison with floating-point values.

Upon exit from the `with` there are two files on the store. I discard the original and rename the new version to the name of the original.

```
with open('sample_name.txt') as sample, open('temp.txt', 'w') as temp:
    for line in sample:
        first, second = line.strip().split()
        if 0 <= float(second) < 0.2:
            temp.write('%s %s 1\n' % (first, second))
        else:
            temp.write('%s %s\n' % (first, second))

from os import remove, rename

remove('sample_name.txt')
rename('temp.txt', 'sample_name.txt')
```

Comment: I can't think of a situation where `line.strip().split() != line.split()`, but perhaps you are using `strip()` for pedagogical purposes?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: You are right, of course. A bit like 'belt and braces'.

Answer (score 0):

Write a modified file then overwrite the original.

```
import os
fname = "sample_name.txt"
temp_fname = fname + ".tmp"
with open(fname, 'r') as fin, open(temp_fname, 'w') as fout:
    for line in fin:
        parts = line.split()
        if 0 < float(parts[1]) < 0.2:
            parts.append("1")
            fout.write(' '.join(parts) + '\n')
        else:
            fout.write(line)
os.remove(fname)
os.rename(temp_fname, fname)
```

If you instead want to always modify the line (adding a `'1'` for when the condition passes and a `'0'` for when it doesn't) change your for-loop to:

```
    for line in fin:
        parts = line.split()
        parts.append("1" if 0 < int(parts[1]) < 0.2 else "0")
        fout.write(' '.join(parts) + '\n')
```